# What is this aircraft-like object at Sea-Tac Airport?

Tags: aircraft-identification, feature-identification

Looking at the Seattle-Tacoma International Airport on Google maps, I noticed at [47°27'47.8"N 122°18'15.5"W](https://www.google.com/maps/place/47%C2%B027%2747.8%22N+122%C2%B018%2715.5%22W/@47.463284,-122.304302,241m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x54649c9da1de86ca!8m2!3d47.4632778!4d-122.3043056) something that looks like a jet aircraft, but with folded wings and a tiny empennage. It's just left of centre in the image below; I've included a couple of nearby aircraft at the top for scale and comparison.

[image]

What is this object? It looks superficially like an aircraft, but I've never seen a non-carrier jet aircraft that folded so much of its wing and the empennage is surely far too small to provide sufficient stability and control for flight.

Could it perhaps be some sort of training platform for ground crew (regular or emergency), with folding simulated wings to make it easier to store?

Comment: Congratulations on achieving 1000 reputation and unlocking new privileges!

Comment: This is definitely not real aircraft. Most probably, it is for firefighting/deicing practice. At London Heathrow, they have a model of a 747 with three engines, and it is intended for ground training purposes.